# Create Eclipse project from existing source

Tags: java, eclipse

I would like to figure out how to create an Eclipse project on top of existing Java source code on my laptop, without changing the source code or directory structure at all.

I have a folder: /Users/myname/test

Within the folder is a single Java source file:

```
package test;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Test.");
  }
}
```

At the command line, I have an environment variable: `CLASSPATH=/Users/myname`

At the command line, I can compile the source file with:  `javac Test.java`
and run it with: `java test.Test`

How can I create a new Eclipse project that allows me to edit and run my program without having to change anything about the code, package, or directory structure?

Comment: Your home directory is a bad location to put on a classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You create a new eclipse project as normal, and not in that location. Anywhere else. then configure that dir to be the source dir *and* the target (build) dir, which is weird (normally they're part of your project dir, but it's not a requirement).

This is a bizarre way to work, but that will work.